# No visible @interface for 'Person' declares the selector 'setEmployeeID:'

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import "Person.h"
@interface Employee : Person {
    int employeeID;
}
@property int employeeID;
@end

#import "Employee.h"
@implementation Employee
@synthesize employeeID;
@end
```

Below code gives an error No visible @interface for 'Person' declares the selector 'setEmployeeID:'. Any idea how to fix this issue?

```
Person *person = [[Employee alloc] init];
[person setEmployeeID:15];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple type error. you alloc a Employee but assign it to a variable of type person

a person has no employeeID

either assign it to Employee var OR use id OR cast ...